# Lightweight RSA Encryption PHP

Tags: php, encryption

So I need to authenticate unique users, so each user will have their own priv/pub keypair. I'm trying to make a lightweight class that can generate a key pair, and then encrypt or decrypt data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class RSA
{
    public $pubkey = '';
    public $privkey = '';

    public function genKeys()
    {
        /* Create the private and public key */
        $res = openssl_pkey_new();

        /* Extract the private key from $res to $privKey */
        openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
        $this->privkey = $privKey;

        /* Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey */
        $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
        $pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

        $this->pubkey = $pubKey;
    }

    public function encrypt($data)
    {
        $data = '';
        if (openssl_private_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $this->privkey))
            $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
        return $data;
    }

    public function decrypt($data)
    {
        $data = '';
        if (openssl_public_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $decrypted, $this->pubkey))
            $data = $decrypted;
        return $data;
    }
}
```

I'm encrypting the data and then decrypting and echoing the plain text but it always returns blank?

```
$RSA = new RSA();
$RSA->genKeys();

$text = "Hello World.";

$e = $RSA->encrypt($text);
$m = $RSA->decrypt($e);

echo "Encrypted: $e <br />";
echo "Decrypted: $m <br />";
```

Any ideas? and I don't want to use heavy extensive libraries. Lightweight as possible would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the base encoding and got it to work:

```
class RSA
{
    public $privKey = '';
    public $pubKey = '';

    public function genKeys()
    {
        $res = openssl_pkey_new();

        // Get private key
        openssl_pkey_export($res, $priv);
        $this->privKey = $priv;

        // Get public key
        $pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
        $this->pubKey = $pubkey["key"];
    }

    public function private_encrypt( $tocrypt )
    {
        $output = "";
        openssl_private_encrypt($tocrypt, $output, $this->privKey);
        return $output;
    }

    public function public_decrypt( $tocrypt )
    {
        $output = "";
        openssl_public_decrypt($tocrypt, $output, $this->pubKey);
        return $output;
    }
}

$RSA = new RSA();
$RSA->genKeys();

$m = "hi";

$e = $RSA->private_encrypt( $m );

echo $RSA->public_decrypt( $e );
```